# Plot matplotlib histogram legend on separate figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a line plot obtained with `ax.plot()`, I have the following handy code to plot the legend on a separate figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 2], label='a', linestyle='--')
ax.plot([-1, 1], label='b', linestyle='dotted')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 4), constrained_layout=True)
fig.legend(ax.lines, [l.get_label() for l in ax.lines], 
           loc="upper center")
```

However if I do this with a histogram (using `ax.hist()`), `ax.lines` is empty and I cannot get the labels and styles used. Is it possible to do that still ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.random.randn(1000, 3)
colors = ['red', 'tan', 'lime']
_,_,patches = ax.hist(x, 10, color=colors, label=colors)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 4), constrained_layout=True)
fig.legend([p[0] for p in patches], [p[0].get_label() for p in patches], 
           loc="upper center")
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE** as per comment: you can achieve the same using `ax.patches` instead of `patches` returned by `ax.hist` like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.random.randn(1000, 3)
colors = ['red', 'tan', 'lime']
n_bins = 10
ax.hist(x, n_bins, color=colors, label=colors)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 4), constrained_layout=True)
fig.legend(ax.patches[::n_bins], [p.get_label() for p in ax.patches[::n_bins]], loc="upper center")
```

Comment: actually what I like with my code for lines is that I need not modify the code used to plot (i.e. no need to do `lines = ax.plot()` or here use `patch` as you do). Would it be possible to get the patches using only the `ax` object ?

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand what you mean (and why) but I've updated my answer for this case.

Comment: Or maybe you want to create only the legend without plotting anything, i.e. without creating the first figure? In this case you can use a proxy artist like so: `fig.legend([matplotlib.patches.Patch(color=c) for c in colors], colors, loc="upper center")`

Comment: I've seen you un-accepted the answer. Does the update solve your question? If not please comment. Thanks.